# What is the correct way to change an IP address from the CLI?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ip, ifconfig

So, I'm a linux admin of many years, however, this still annoyingly throws me.

If I have a server with a static ip set in /etc/networking/interfaces and change the IP, what is the best way to actually make the machine use this?

It used to just be a case of `/etc/init.d/networking restart` many years ago, but, something happened in an update a few years ago, and this just doesn't work any more.

Other things are `ifdown <interface> && ifup <interface>` or `ifconfig <interface> down && ifconfig <interface up`

However, none of these seem to work and I always now just end up rebooting the server for speed.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Network manager is common on desktops with gui, but netplan is used on server having replaced what you have in your memory some time ago. The Ubuntu wiki (documentation) refers you to https://netplan.io/

Comment: what version of Ubuntu?  ifconfig is deprecated since 18.04 or so.

Comment: For Ubuntu Server, see NETPLAN [https://netplan.io/] and also this https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html